# Grepping output of command in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I'm trying to search for file that match a given pattern using `grep`.

This works fine when typed directly into the terminal, returns all files with "zips" in the path.

```
svn st -u ~/includes ~/scripts ~/htdocs/intra ~/htdocs/update ~/htdocs/sponsor ~/survey ~/htdocs/coupon | grep "zips"
```

I want to add this functionality to a bash script so I can just call `check zips`

This is what I've got, but it's ignoring everything after the pipe and returning all output of the first command.

```
#!/bin/bash
QU=$1
svn st -u ~/includes ~/scripts ~/htdocs/intra ~/htdocs/update
~/htdocs/sponsor ~/survey ~/htdocs/coupon | grep "$QU"
```

How can I get this bash script to honor the `grep` call?

Comment: when i run the bash script as shown above, it returns the full output of `svn st -u ~/includes ~/scripts ~/htdocs/intra ~/htdocs/update
~/htdocs/sponsor ~/survey ~/htdocs/coupon` and ignores the ` | grep "$QU"`

Comment: Make sure the whole pipe is really all on one line in the file; if there's a newline in there you'd have to remove or escape it.

Comment: @TextGeek that was the problem. Nano was adding linebreaks i didn't notice.

Comment: Dang, I should have made that an answer instead of a comment, so the upvotes would count... :)  Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @TextGeek, please, by all means go ahead. i don't get my little 2 points unless someone posts an answer for me to accept anyway :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the whole pipe is really all on one line in the file; if there's a newline in there you'd have to remove or escape it.

:)